# Does my graphics card have to be compatible with the motherboard chipset?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, chipset, crossfire

I am looking to purchase to Radeon HD 7850's, these particularly,

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16814150641

I want to run them in Crossfire on this motherboard,

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16813128651

However the motherboard states that it's chipset is 970, and according to an AMD crossfire chipset compatibility chart for this video card, the chipset is not listed.

EDIT - This image is the chart I refer to, http://sites.amd.com/PublishingImages/Public/Graphic_Illustrations/WebBannerJPEG/AMD_CrossfireX_Chart_1618W.jpg

Will I be able to crossfire both of these GPUs above on the motherboard detailed above?

Comment: Where exactly is this AMD crossfire chipset compatability information?  The motherboard has support for 2-way Crossfire I see no evidence that indicates the cards you want wouldn't work in the configuration you want.

Comment: @Ramhound This image, http://sites.amd.com/PublishingImages/Public/Graphic_Illustrations/WebBannerJPEG/AMD_CrossfireX_Chart_1618W.jpg The 970 chipset is not listed below.

Comment: The chart isn't current. Its missing their current flagship products. The motherboard supports Crossfire thats all you need to know.  If you need additional confirmation.  The chart does not indicate that its NOT compatible.  The chart does not list all current chipsets.  Haswell isn't even listed for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insights @Ramhound , been building rigs for awhile but never really examined the chipsets too closely, things just kind of worked regardless of them ;) Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossfire will work as long as the video cards and motherboard both support it.  In this case it does appear everything will work great.  The compatibility chart is missing newer chipsets, and does not exclude any specifically.  Essentially, as long as you buy two identical graphics cards and install the bridge, it should work great!

Comment: Actually it is missing a few from the same generation but your point remains true.  As you point out the chart is simply not complete